# My bot doesn't reply with the correct latency

Tags: python, discord.py

I created a ping command that responds with the bot latency using this code:

```
# To ping the bot (latency)
  @commands.command()
  async def ping(self, ctx):
    try:
      latency = round(client.latency * 1000, 1)
      await ctx.send(f"Pong! Latency: {latency}ms")
    except:
      await ctx.send(f"Error getting latency")
```

However, the bot replies with "Pong! Latency: nanms", instead of "Pong! Latency: ms" I didn't find any errors with the code, but for some reason, it says that it is not a number. Can you help me find the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your command with:

```py
@commands.command()
async def ping(self,ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Pong! Latency:*{round(self.client.latency * 1000)} ms"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify With This

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self,ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"**{round(self.bot.latency * 1000)}** ms"))
```

it wont be client latency it will be `self.bot.latency`

Comment: self has no attribute `bot`

Comment: replace bot with client